# Convert Java object to XML string

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Yes, yes I know that lots of questions were asked about this topic. But I still cannot find the solution to my problem. I have a property annotated Java object. For example Customer, [like in this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/). And I want a String representation of it. Google reccomends using JAXB for such purposes. But in all examples created XML file is printed to file or console, like this:

```
File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

// output pretty printed
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, file);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
```

But I have to use this object and send over network in XML format. So I want to get a String which represents XML.

```
String xmlString = ...
sendOverNetwork(xmlString);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can use the Marshaler's method for marshaling which takes a [Writer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) as parameter:

> [marshal(Object,Writer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshal%28java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Writer%29)

and pass it an Implementation which can build a String object

> **Direct Known Subclasses:**
>   BufferedWriter, CharArrayWriter, FilterWriter, OutputStreamWriter, PipedWriter, PrintWriter, [StringWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html)

Call its [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html#toString()) method to get the actual String value.

So doing:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, sw);
String xmlString = sw.toString();
```

Comment: `StringWriter` is very old. Under the covers it uses [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) where a much faster approach would have been to use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) but that didn't exist when StringWriter was first made. Because of this every call to `sw.toString()` implies synchronization. Bad if you're looking for performance.

Comment: @peterh All answers here use a StringWriter. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

Use this to get the exact structure of XML.

Comment: For org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller you can use:
```final StringResult result = new StringResult();
jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(customer, result);
String xmlString = result.toString();```

Answer (score 54):

A convenient option is to use [javax.xml.bind.JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html):

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JAXB.marshal(customer, sw);
String xmlString = sw.toString();
```

The [**reverse**] process (unmarshal) would be:

```
Customer customer = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlString), Customer.class);
```

No need to deal with checked exceptions in this approach.

Comment: This won't copy fields that have only getters

Comment: `JAXB.marshal()` is really convenient. I tried around to set up a marshaller object. But it only accepts objects with `@XmlRootElement` annotation and causes a bunch of other problems...

Answer (score 36):

As A4L mentioning, you can use StringWriter. Providing here example code:

```
private static String jaxbObjectToXML(Customer customer) {
    String xmlString = "";
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();

        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE); // To format XML

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        m.marshal(customer, sw);
        xmlString = sw.toString();

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return xmlString;
}
```

Comment: no need in StringWriter
m.marshal(customer, System.out);

Answer (score 6):

You can marshal it to a [`StringWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) and grab its string. from `toString()`.

Comment: @KickButtowski: The essential part of the answer is just to use a `StringWriter`.  The link is just documentation.

Comment: please add some explanation and gladly I remove my down vote. :) beside you can put this as a comment

Comment: Can you provide an example usage of it?

Comment: @Bob: Create a `StringWriter`, pass it to `marshal()`, call `toString()`.

Comment: @Bob this answer is actually sufficient. Please learn how to research the APIs, in this example `Marshaller` has several marshal overloaded methods, just take a look at their parameters and what they are for and you'll find out the answer.

Answer (score 6):

**To convert an Object to XML in Java**

Customer.java

```
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
*
* @author ABsiddik
*/

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

int id;
String name;
int age;

String address;
ArrayList<String> mobileNo;


 public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@XmlAttribute
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@XmlElement
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

@XmlElement
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

@XmlElement
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public ArrayList<String> getMobileNo() {
    return mobileNo;
}

@XmlElement
public void setMobileNo(ArrayList<String> mobileNo) {
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
}


}
```

ConvertObjToXML.java

```
package com;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

/**
*
* @author ABsiddik
*/
public class ConvertObjToXML {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<String> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
    numberList.add("01942652579");
    numberList.add("01762752801");
    numberList.add("8800545");

    Customer c = new Customer();

    c.setId(23);
    c.setName("Abu Bakar Siddik");
    c.setAge(45);
    c.setAddress("Dhaka, Bangladesh");
    c.setMobileNo(numberList);

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\NETIZEN-ONE\\Desktop \\customer.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(c, file);// this line create customer.xml file in specified path.

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(c, sw);
    String xmlString = sw.toString();

    System.out.println(xmlString);
}

}
```

Try with this example..

Comment: Best answer normal object with @xml annotations pretty well working solution thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Testing And working Java code to convert java object to XML:

**Customer.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id;
    String desc;
    ArrayList<String> list;

    public ArrayList<String> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setList(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public String getDesc()
    {
        return desc;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setDesc(String desc)
    {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**createXML.java**

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;


public class createXML {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.setAge(45);
        c.setDesc("some desc ");
        c.setId(23);
        c.setList(list);
        c.setName("name");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(c, sw);
        String xmlString = sw.toString();
        System.out.println(xmlString);
    }

}
```

Comment: Generally adding answers that just include code and no explanation are frowned upon

Answer (score 2):

Here is a util class for marshaling and unmarshaling objects. In my case it was a nested class, so I made it static JAXBUtils.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class JAXBUtils
{
    /**
     * Unmarshal an XML string
     * @param xml     The XML string
     * @param type    The JAXB class type.
     * @return The unmarshalled object.
     */
    public <T> T unmarshal(String xml, Class<T> type)
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
        return javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(reader, type);
    }

    /**
     * Marshal an Object to XML.
     * @param object    The object to marshal.
     * @return The XML string representation of the object.
     */
    public String marshal(Object object)
    {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        JAXB.marshal(object, stringWriter);
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ByteArrayOutputStream

```
public static String printObjectToXML(final Object object) throws TransformerFactoryConfigurationError,
        TransformerConfigurationException, SOAPException, TransformerException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    XMLEncoder xmlEncoder = new XMLEncoder(baos);
    xmlEncoder.writeObject(object);
    xmlEncoder.close();

    String xml = baos.toString();
    System.out.println(xml);

    return xml.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Some Generic code to create XML Stirng

*object -->  is Java class to convert it to XML*
*name -->  is just name space like thing - for differentiate*

```
public static String convertObjectToXML(Object object,String name) {
          try {
              StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
              JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass());
              Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
              jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
              QName qName = new QName(object.getClass().toString(), name);
              Object root = new JAXBElement<Object>(qName,java.lang.Object.class, object);
              jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root, stringWriter);
              String result = stringWriter.toString();
              System.out.println(result);
              return result;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the JAXB.marshal implementation and added jaxb.fragment=true to remove the XML prolog. This method can handle objects even without the XmlRootElement annotation. This also throws the unchecked DataBindingException.

```
public static String toXmlString(Object o) {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true); // remove xml prolog
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); // formatted output

        final QName name = new QName(Introspector.decapitalize(clazz.getSimpleName()));
        JAXBElement jaxbElement = new JAXBElement(name, clazz, o);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, sw);
        return sw.toString();

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new DataBindingException(e);
    }
}
```

If the compiler warning bothers you, here's the templated, two parameter version.

```
public static <T> String toXmlString(T o, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true); // remove xml prolog
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); // formatted output

        QName name = new QName(Introspector.decapitalize(clazz.getSimpleName()));
        JAXBElement jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<>(name, clazz, o);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, sw);
        return sw.toString();

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new DataBindingException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is one example of Java Class, different set of annotations to generate xml, CDATA and JaxB code to generate XML.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="customer")
public class Customer {
   
   @XmlElement(name = "first-name")
   String firstName;
   @XmlElement(name = "last-name")
   String lastName;
   
   @XmlElement(name= "customer-address")
   private Address address;
   
   @XmlElement(name= "bio")
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AdapterCDATA.class)
   private Biography bio;
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {
   
   @XmlElement(name = "house-number")
   String houseNumber;
   @XmlElement(name = "address-line-1")
   String addLine1;
   
   @XmlElement(name = "address-line-2")
   String addLine2;
   
  }
```

Adaptor Class

```
    public class AdaptorCDATA extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String marshal(String arg0) throws Exception {
        return "<![CDATA[" + arg0 + "]]>";
    }
    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String arg0) throws Exception {
        return arg0;
    }
}
```

JAXB code to generat XML

```
  public String xmlStringForCustomer(Customer customer) {
 
   JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal(customer,writer);
    return writer.toString();
}
```

Above Code will generate an xml like below

```
<customer>
 <first-name></first-name>
 <last-name></last-name>
 <customer-address> 
     <house-number></house-number>
     <address-line-1></address-line-1>
     <address-line-2></address-line-2>
 </customer-address>
 <bio>
   <![CDATA[ **bio data will come here**]]>
 </bio>
< /customer>
```

Comment: What is sw? marshaller.marshal(customer,sw)??

Comment: Corrected the code snippet, sw meant to be the variable name for StringWriter, which was called writer in one line and sw in other 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) can construct XML string with help of a builder.

```
    class Customer {
        String name;
        int age;
        int id;
    }
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.name = "John";
    customer.age = 30;
    customer.id = 12345;

    String xml = U.objectBuilder().add("customer", U.objectBuilder()
        .add("name", customer.name)
        .add("age", customer.age)
        .add("id", customer.id)).toXml();

    // <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    //    <customer>
    //      <name>John</name>
    //      <age number="true">30</age>
    //      <id number="true">12345</id>
    //    </customer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Spring Webservices framework you can use `org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller`:

```
final StringResult result = new StringResult();
jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(customer, result);
String xmlString = result.toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

private String generateXml(Object obj, Class objClass) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(objClass);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, sw);
        return sw.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this function to convert Object  to xml string 
(should be called as convertToXml(sourceObject, Object.class); )-->

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public static <T> String convertToXml(T source, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
    String result;
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    QName qName = new QName(StringUtils.uncapitalize(clazz.getSimpleName()));
    JAXBElement<T> root = new JAXBElement<T>(qName, clazz, source);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root, sw);
    result = sw.toString();
    return result;
}
```

Use this function to convert xml string to Object back -->
(should be called as `createObjectFromXmlString(xmlString, Object.class)`)

```
public static <T> T createObjectFromXmlString(String xml, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException, IOException{

    T value = null;
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml); 
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<T> rootElement=jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(reader),clazz);
    value = rootElement.getValue();
    return value;
}
```