# Making SOAP Request using OkHttp library Android

Tags: android, soap, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to make SOAP Call via OkHttp library so I can upgrade to Retrofit Library use .
I have gone through said post .

[OkHttp](https://www.studytutorial.in/android-sending-xml-or-soap-rest-api-request-using-okhttp-tutorial) . Link

Library Used in Gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

I have successfully made the call  , but the Response Code comes as 415 .
I have changed the content type as

Have tested with

```
.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
```

and

```
.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"; charset=utf-8")
```

and

```
.addHeader("Content-Type", "html/text"; charset=utf-8")
```

also

What could be the problem

My Request Format

```
final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
                .addHeader("soapaction", "http://tempuri.org/Login")
                .post(body)
                .build();
```

Other Code :

```
final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        soapRequest = Login(userName.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(SOAP_MEDIA_TYPE, soapRequest);

        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
                .addHeader("soapaction", "http://tempuri.org/Login")
                .post(body)
                .build();


        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                String mMessage = e.getMessage().toString();
                Log.w("failure Response", mMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                String mMessage = response.body().string();

                Log.i("",mMessage);

             //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Result :"+mMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //code = response.code();
              //  getResponse(mMessage, response);

            }
        });
```

Function Login

```
 public  String Login(String name,String password) {

        String body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
                "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
                "  <soap:Body>\n" +
                "    <Login xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n" +
                "      <Name>"+userName+"</Name>\n" +
                "      <Password>"+password+"</Password>\n" +
                "    </Login>\n" +
                "  </soap:Body>\n" +
                "</soap:Envelope>";

        return body;
    }
```

Comment: I think problem with soapRequest = Login(userName.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString()); please try to fix it https://stackoverflow.com/a/34902666/2298357

Comment: Please check its my soap request

Comment: Have you tried "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"?

Comment: Still gave the same error : 415  Unsupported Media Type

Comment: If I try it with HTTP request it works fine ... but not with OkHttp library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the below code

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/xml");

String soap = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
            " <soap:Body>\n" + " <Login xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n" +
            " <Name>"+userName+"</Name>\n" + " <Password>"+password+"</Password>\n" +
            " </Login>\n" + " </soap:Body>\n" + "</soap:Envelope>";

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, soap);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(YOUR_LINK)
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("content-type", "text/xml")
            .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a request with attachment in soup?