# How to print XML response to console in JAX-RS web service?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jax-ws

I am trying to print the response of a JAX-RS web service GET method into the console. The output as can be seen in Postman is what I am trying to print to the eclipse console. Is this possible?

JAX-RS method:

```
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public List<BankAccount> getBankAccounts(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello " + request.getRequestURL().toString());

    return BankAccountDao.instance.getBankAccounts();
}
```

Dao method:

```
    public List<BankAccount> getBankAccounts() {
    List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();

    try {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM BANKACCOUNT");
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount(rs.getString("BRANCH_CODE"), rs.getString("ACCOUNT_NUMBER"), rs.getString("CUST_NAME"), rs.getString("CUST_ADDRESS"), rs.getInt("cust_rating"), rs.getInt("balance"));
            bankAccounts.add(bankAccount);
        }
        return bankAccounts;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("\nSQLException");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bankAccounts;
}
```

[The Postman output (what I am trying to print in my Eclipse console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y83Hf.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far? did u try to print the value of `BankAccountDao.instance.getBankAccounts()` in the JAX-RS method before returning it? If so what is the output?

Comment: It gave me back this: [ca2.BankAccount@56ddf6c3, ca2.BankAccount@3dd7f5e5, ca2.BankAccount@3092c573, ca2.BankAccount@6a10a43c, ca2.BankAccount@53c22c53]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959343/convert-java-object-to-xml-string

Comment: Use Jersey's LoggingFilter or LoggingFeature (depending on the Jersey version you are using). This will allow you to log the request to the console.